# String wrong input

Tags: python, string, printing

I am having trouble printing the right output. Here is my output:

```
ere-Hay
are-ay
he-tay
ords-way
```

This is what I am expecting to get:

```
ere-Hay
are-ay
e-thay
ords-way
```

My code, something is not right in toPigLatin:

```
isVowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')   

def toPigLatin(word):
    letter1 = word[0]
    if letter1 in isVowels:
        return word + "-ay" 
    else:
        return (word[1:] + "-" + word[0] + "ay")   

def main():
    #filename = input("Enter filename: ")
    filename = "some.txt"

    for word in open(filename):
        print(toPigLatin (word.strip()))

main()
```

This is my some.txt:

```
Here
are
the
words
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: WHy are you expecting the output for 'the' to 'e-thay' instead of 'he-tay'? You output is correct for the code you have written

Comment: @praveen because I am supposed to bring all the non-vowels to the end of the word and add "-ay". If the word starts with a vowel then just add '-ay" at the end of the word.

Comment: Not exactly code-related, but in pig latin you move the first letter to the end of the word and add 'ay' to it. So why are you expecting it to move he first 2 letters (th) for 'the' on the third line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isVowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')___

def toPigLatin(word):
    letter1 = word[0]
    if letter1 in isVowels:
        return word + "-ay"_
    else:
        prefix = ''
        for letter in word:
            if letter in isVowels:
                break
            else:
                prefix += letter
        return (word[len(prefix):] + "-" + prefix + "ay")___

def main():
    #filename = input("Enter filename: ")
    filename = "some.txt"

    for word in open(filename):
        print(toPigLatin (word.strip()))

main()
```

This produces the output:

```
ere-Hay
are-ay
e-thay
ords-way
```